# how to override the timeline-twitter css

Tags: 7, social-network

I embedded a feed from twitter into a block and I am trying to override the size of font by adding this to my css , but it still only picks up the css that is coming from twitter.  is there any way to override this on my drupal site without logging into their twitter page?

.timeline-Tweet-text {
       font-size: 18px; !important;
       line-height: 24px;
       font-weight: 300;
   }

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to style it, you'll need to stop using the standard twitter embed code and use another solution.

I suggest using the Twitter (https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) and Oauth (https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth) modules for this.

This will allow you to create a view of your feed which you will be able to style easily.

There looks to be a pretty good recipe here: http://polso.info/integrating-twitter-feed-your-drupal-site

Good luck!
Anne

Comment: thanks the problem is i dont have the user name and password of the twitter feed.

Comment: Hmm - that's a tough one. There are other modules like Tweet Feed, but I think all of them are going to require the API key of the account(s) in question. I'm not aware of one that doesn't.

Comment: Hey - I think I was mistaken: I had a chance to work with the Twitter module today. Based on the UI options and instructions (see this screenshot: http://imgur.com/2U9ydni), it looks like you just have to add one Twitter key (e.g., your own account) and then you can "add an unauthenticated account". You can then create views based on feeds, which you will have greater control over when styling.